# Login using Rails backend and Google Omniauth

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication

I want to building an Android-Web App, so I started with the login. I know how to login to google using the gem omniauth-google-oauth2 and google apis in rails, also I know how to login to google using google apis on android. My question is, there is a way to register my login from an android app to my rails app?

For example, If I enter to
`localhost:3000/login` 
and I'm not logged, rails must render my login view (Something like "Login with Google"), but If I login from my android app, rails should redirect me to my welcome page.

I've been reading and only found either how to login to google using android or rails. The best info I found so far is [this](https://github.com/elcurator/android-google-plus-omniauth-tutorial), the only problem is that only register my login, it doesn't redirect me to another page.

I think my main problem is rails. I've got some experience developing in android, but I'm kinda new in rails.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? care to share the solution?